# Passing a structure with array of another structure from C# to C (P/Invoke)

Tags: c#, c, struct, pinvoke

I have the following structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TCurve
{
    public int fNumItems;             /* Number of TRatePts in fArray */
    public IntPtr fArray;          /* Dates & rates */ // pointer to an array of TRatePt[]
    public long fBaseDate;            /* Discount date */
    public double fBasis;         //ZERO_CURVE_BASIS in capvoll.c which is #defined as ANNUAL_BASIS 1   /* Number compounding periods / year */
    public long fDayCountConv;   //ZERO_CURVE_DAY_COUNT_CONV in capvoll.c which is #defined as GTO_ACT_365F; = 2L /* How the year fraction is computed */
    public IntPtr     fClassHandle;  /* C++ class handle implementation */
};
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TRatePt
{
    public long fDate;
    public double fRate;
};
```

The TRatePt is defined as follows:

```
[DllImport("alib.dll", EntryPoint = "GtoCapFloorAvgVol")]
    public static extern int CapFloorAvgVol(
        long capStartDate,                  /* (I)  */
        long capExpiryDate,                 /* (I) */
        double[] strikeRates,                /* (I) */
        int numStrikeRates,                  /* (I) */
        double[] principles,                 /* (I) */
        int numPrinciples,                   /* (I) */
        int moneymarketDen,                  /* (I) # days/year */
        ref TDateInterval resetPeriod,       /* (I) Time Between caplets */
        int optionType,                      /* (I) Cap or Floor */
        char stubPosition,                   /* (I) 2/16/94 GG 'F'ront or 'B'ack */
        [In] IntPtr zeroCurve,                /* (I) For discounting Pointer to TCurve*/
        double price,                        /* (I) Price */
        double avgVolGuess,                  /* (I) Average Volatility guess */
        out double avgVol);                  /* (O) Average Volatility */
```

The C declaration is:

```
GTO_EXPORT(int )  GtoCapFloorAvgVol(
TDate capStartDate,                  /* (I)  */
TDate capExpiryDate,                 /* (I) */
double *strikeRates,                 /* (I) */
int numStrikeRates,                  /* (I) */
double *principles,                  /* (I) */
int numPrinciples,                   /* (I) */
int moneymarketDen,                  /* (I) # days/year */
TDateInterval *resetPeriod,          /* (I) Time Between caplets */
int optionType,                      /* (I) Cap or Floor */
char stubPosition,                   /* (I) 2/16/94 GG 'F'ront or 'B'ack */
TCurve *zeroCurve,                   /* (I) For discounting */
double price,                        /* (I) Price */
double avgVolGuess,                  /* (I) Average Volatility guess */
double *avgVol)                      /* (O) Average Volatility */
```

Thanks in advance!

Ok so here are the C structs:

```
typedef struct _TCurve{
int       fNumItems;     /* Number of TRatePts in fArray */
TRatePt  *fArray;        /* Dates & rates */
TDate     fBaseDate;     /* Discount date */ 
double    fBasis;        /* Number compounding periods / year */
long      fDayCountConv; /* How the year fraction is computed */
void     *fClassHandle;  /* C++ class handle implementation */ } TCurve;
```

and :

```
typedef struct{
TDate  fDate;
double fRate;} TRatePt;
```

By the way if you know how to handle the void* help would be welcome...

PS: TDate is just a 
`typedef long int TDate;`

And here is how I use it:

```
TCurve _zeroCurve = new TCurve()
                        {
                            fBaseDate = _tempValueDate,
                            fNumItems = _ratePoints.Length,
                            fBasis = 2L,
                            fDayCountConv = 1
                        };
        int _sizeOfTCurve = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TCurve));
        IntPtr p_zeroCurve = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(_sizeOfTCurve);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(_zeroCurve, p_zeroCurve, false);

        int _status;
        _zeroCurve.fArray = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(_ratePoints.Length * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TRatePt)));
        try
        {
            IntPtr _ratePt = _zeroCurve.fArray;
            for (int _i = 0; _i < _ratePoints.Length; _i++)
            {
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(_ratePoints[_i], _ratePt, false);
                //_ratePt = new IntPtr(_ratePt.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TRatePt)));
                IntPtr _nextRatePt = new IntPtr(_ratePt.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TRatePt)));
                _ratePt = _nextRatePt;
                //_ratePt += Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TRatePt));
            }
            _status = CapFloorAvgVol(_tempStartDate, _temPexpiryDate, strikeRates, strikeRates.Length, principles, principles.Length, moneymarketDen,
                                            ref _resetPeriod, optionType, stubPosition, p_zeroCurve, price, avgVolGuess, out avgVol);
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(_zeroCurve.fArray);
        }

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p_zeroCurve);
        p_zeroCurve = IntPtr.Zero;
```

Comment: Can you give us the C Declarations for the structs?

Comment: Also, a `long` in C really means `int` in C# - a `long long` in C is a `long` in C#.

Comment: You will need to marshal the array manually. Which direction is it going in? In or out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's how to do what I think you mean, and I'm sorry it took me so long to work it out. You will need to use manual marshalling for the pointer to `TCurve`.

I've simplified your struct for convenience.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TCurve
{
    public int fNumItems;            
    public IntPtr fArray;//you need to marshal this manually
};
...
[DllImport("alib.dll", EntryPoint = "GtoCapFloorAvgVol")]
public static extern int CapFloorAvgVol(
    ...
    TCurve ref zeroCurve,
    ...
);
...
TCurve curve = new TCurve();
TRatePt[] items = new TRatePt[2];
//for example, but you'd have the items coming in as a parameter I guess

curve.fNumItems = items.Length;
curve.fArray = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(items.Length * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TRatePt)));
try
{
    IntPtr item = curve.fArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(items[i], item, false);
        item = new IntPtr(item.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TRatePt))); 
    }
    //now call the function passing the curve struct
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(curve.fArray);
}
```

I doubt that the `Pack = 1` is correct. It's pretty rare to pack structs in C.

Another problem is that `long` is 64 bits in C# but `long int`, `long`, `int` are all 32 bits in C++ on Windows.

Finally, the `void*` parameter is an opaque pointer and you should declare it as `IntPtr` in your C# struct.

Comment: Thanks, do I also need to do this to pass TCurve to the function?

Comment: Yes of course! Your TCurve has all the other fields in too. I've just removed them and concentrated on the bit you were stuck on.

Comment: Sorry I meant do I need to pass it as an IntPtr as well or is a ref TCurve ok?

Comment: I am getting these errors:

Error 37 Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.IntPtr' and 'int'


Error 38 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.IntPtr'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I'm on .net 4. You must be on an earlier version. Read this to learn how to cope with the missing capability: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/11/11/properly-incrementing-an-intptr.aspx

Comment: Indeed I'm in .NET 2.0. I'll check the article out. Thank you

Comment: After so many false starts, I hope I've finally got you on the right track. And once again, sorry for being so bone headed with my previous efforts.

Comment: I tried doing this instead:
`IntPtr _nextRatePt = new IntPtr(_ratePt.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TRatePt)));
    _ratePt = _nextRatePt;
`

Instead of the pointer arithmetic line but now I get access violation errors...

Comment: Sorry, comments are too limiting to really understand. Could you update your Q to include your latest code?

Comment: You aren't doing what I said! There is no need for the p_zeroCurve stuff. All you've done there is take a copy of _zeroCurve, modify _zeroCurve and then pass the copy (p_zeroCurve) which still contains the contents before you modified _zeroCurve. The zeroCurve parameter to CapFloorAvgVol should be typed as TCurve ref zeroCurve.

Comment: I updated the answer to make it a little clearer what I mean in that comment

Comment: Ok sorry, I put a comment regarding whether I needed to allocate _zeroCurve on the global heap also earlier and thought you had said yes... My mistake

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that comment

Comment: I actually thought that
Marshal.StructureToPtr(_zeroCurve, p_zeroCurve, false);
made the pointer point to _zeroCurve. Haven't manipulated pointers for a bit. Thanks a million... At least now I understand my mistake.

Comment: "StructureToPtr copies the contents of structure to the pre-allocated block of memory that the ptr parameter points to." Taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr.aspx).

Comment: Is `long int` in your C++ compiler a 64 bit value? I suspect not. In C# long is 64 bits. On Windows C/C++, long it 32 bits.

Comment: Hmm my dll is compiled in 64 bit if that answers your first question (I don't know much about 64 bit vs 32 bit and the difference it would imply but my dll is 64 bit)...

Comment: Doesn't matter whether it is 32 or 64 bit, integer sizes don't change. I've checked, `long int` is 32 bits wide.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt it working with unsafe structs ?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct TCurve
{
    public TRatePt* fArray;          /* Dates & rates */ // pointer to an array of TRatePt[]
};
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct TRatePt
{
    public long fDate;
    public double fRate;
};
```

And then, in your code :

```
unsafe
{
     TCurve _zeroCurve = new TCurve();
     var arr = new TRatePt[]{new TRatePt(), new TRatePt()};
     fixed (TRatePt* pt = arr)
     {
          _zeroCurve.fArray = pt;
          // do sthing while your array is fixed
     }
 }
```

Comment: I didn't try but I think I prefer not working with unsafe code. Anyway, I've solved the issue thanks to @JonathanDisckon